# asp.net script loader master pages and path errors

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, master-pages, dynamic-script-loading

I am using `[script.js][1]` as async script loader along with my master page. The pages on the root are working fine using the master page file as it's master page. When it comes to web pages that are inside folders like below then the path does not work fine. Script loader loads the files from wrong url. How do i make it load from correct url regardless of the path.

```
Admin

-users

 -createuser.aspx
```

The contents of the loader file

```
//show the path to load scripts files from
$script.path("/js/");

//load jquery first and then load the dependent scripts
$script.order(["jquery.min","slider"],function(){
    //load the application specific file
    $script("app");
});
```

how do i get the path to web application on client side for example path should resolve to
`http://domainname/virtualdirectory/js/`

Comment: Hello, Do you need these Dynamic URLs from the JS file or from an Aspx file?

Comment: @HanletEscaño if it was aspx file it would have been easy. It is the js file that i need these urls for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for somthing like this?

```
<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/test.min.js") %>
```

This will resolve the url for you from the HTML side.  I am not familiar with `$script.path`, but I am wondering if you can do somthing like `$script.path('<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/test.min.js") %>');`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `$script.path("~/js");` would be better. Also, please, write down the wrong path here, i'll try to guess why it is wrong

Comment: but the code you give applies to `only aspx` files, it is the `js file` that loads the other scripts. js does not understand what the tilde `~` symbol means

Comment: `http://locahost/virtualdirectory/admin/users/js/jquery.min.js` the script kind of looks in to the current directory to find js directory but sadly `js directory is at the root.`

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

Code Behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string script;
                script = "function getURL(which){ if(which=='1') { return '" + ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx") + "'; } }";
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MyFunction", script, true);
        }
```

JAVASCRIPT-With JQuery:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert(getURL('1'));
    });

</script>
```

you will have to know which URL to load, but it works like a charm. Good luck!